# Test if all elements of a python list are False

Tags: python, list

How to return `False` if all elements are in a list are `False`?

The given list is:

```
data = [False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> data = [False, False, False]
>>> not any(data)
True
```

`any` will return True if there's any truth value in the iterable.

Comment: @Ajay, To use `all`: `all(not x for x in data)`

Comment: Note: this won't work if you are including non-boolean data in the array.

Comment: @HaroldSeefeld, Try `not any([0, 0, 0])`

Comment: @HaroldSeefeld it will, python can test the truthiness of all built in types

Comment: 0, [], {},()..etc are all False non-boolean data..:)

Comment: @HaroldSeefeld is correct in the sense that something like `[0, False, set()]` passes the `not any` test even though not all the elements are `False`. Better would be `any(x is not False for x in data)`.

Comment: How come we never get to hear of these super-cool built-ins? :'(

Comment: What's a nice way to check if all element are True in a list?

Comment: @hi15, See [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) in Python documentation.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. If the list has all `False` values and at least one `np.nan` value, then the `any()` function will return `True`.

Answer (score 51):

Basically there are two functions that deal with an iterable and return True or False depending on which boolean values elements of the sequence evaluate to.

1. `all(iterable)` returns True if all elements of the `iterable` are considered as true values (like `reduce(operator.and_, iterable)`).
2. `any(iterable)` returns True if at least one element of the `iterable` is a true value (again, using functional stuff, `reduce(operator.or_, iterable)`).

Using the `all` function, you can map `operator.not_` over your list or just build a new sequence with negated values and check that all the elements of the new sequence are true:

```
>>> all(not element for element in data)
```

With the `any` function, you can check that at least one element is true and then negate the result since you need to return `False` if there's a true element:

```
>>> not any(data)
```

According to De Morgan's law, these two variants will return the same result, but I would prefer the last one (which uses `any`) because it is shorter, more readable (and can be intuitively understood as "there isn't a true value in data") and more efficient (since you don't build any extra sequences).

Comment: The `any()` solution will stop as soon as it finds a True value and so will usually be faster.

Answer (score 5):

`True` and `False` are the Boolean representations of 0 and 1.
`True` = 1 and `False` = 0

```
data = [False, False, False]    
if sum(data) == 0:
   return False
if sum(data) == len(data):
   return True
```

`sum(data)` represents the addition of `1` and `0` with respective values of True(1) and False(0) in a list.

In the case of all `False` sum is 0,
and in the case of all True` sum is equal to the length of the list.

Any other sum values would mean not all is False or True.

Answer (score 2):

We all know that `False` is also considered `0`, So if `sum` of all elements is `0`, which means all elements within list are `False`.
But since you want:

> to return 'false' because all elements are 'false'

To do that use negation operator `not` or `!`.

```py
data = [False, False, False]
print(sum(data)!=0) #False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using the generator expression:

```
data = [False, False, False]
try:
    out = next(elt for elt in data if elt) # holds the value of first non-empty element
except StopIteration:
    print("all elements are empty")

data = [[], [], [1], [2]]
try:
    out = next(elt for elt in data if elt) # [1]
except StopIteration:
    print("all elements are empty")
```