# Is there a better way of checking if a boolean array contains at least one True value than bool(sum(array)) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, boolean

For example:

```
boolarr = [True, True, False, False, True, True]
atleastonetrue = bool(sum(boolarr))
```

Is there a more elegant or conventional way of doing this?

Comment: One solution is to use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). Not only is more *pythonic* is also faster, it stops once it finds the `True` value.

Comment: `one = any(arr)`

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099561/test-if-all-elements-of-a-python-list-are-false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, `any(arr)` works.