# How do you filter indices based on their matching a condition for every item in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not the exact problem I'm having, but it's an easy to understand equivalent: Imagine you're asked to find the numbers from 0 to 99 which are divisible by all the numbers in a given divisor_list.
This is what I have been able to come up with:

```
divisible_numbers = []
for i in range(100):
    divisible_numbers.append(i)
    for divisor in divisor_list:
        if i % divisor != 0:
            divisible_numbers.pop()
            break
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this?
I've thought of list comprehension but it's erm... not pretty (and also more comparisons than necessary are made):

```
divisible_numbers = [i for i in range(100) 
                     if len([0 for divisor in divisor_list
                             if i % divisor != 0]) == 0]
```

Please don't suggest mathematical solutions (I know there is an easy one), this is about the control flow, not the problem at hand.

Comment: The list comprehension looks reasonable. You could simplify it a bit by using `any` instead of checking that the length of the inner list is zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if all elements of a python list are False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099561/test-if-all-elements-of-a-python-list-are-false)

Comment: i.e., use `[i for i in numbers if not any((i % d) for d in divisor_list)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
divisible_numbers = [i for i in range(100) if all(i % divisor == 0 for divisor in divisor_list)]
```

seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `numpy`

For sample data:

```py
import numpy as np

divisor_list=[3,5,7,9,11,15,18]

divisible_numbers=np.array(list(range(100)))

divisible_numbers=divisible_numbers[(divisible_numbers.reshape(-1,1)%divisor_list==0).any(axis=1)]

>>> divisible_number

[ 0  3  5  6  7  9 10 11 12 14 15 18 20 21 22 24 25 27 28 30 33 35 36 39
 40 42 44 45 48 49 50 51 54 55 56 57 60 63 65 66 69 70 72 75 77 78 80 81
 84 85 87 88 90 91 93 95 96 98 99]
```

Answer (score -1):

lets say `divisor_list = [6,9,69]`

Then you can

```
list(filter(lambda x: max(x%i == 0 for i in divisor_list), [i for i in range(1,100)]))
```

will return

```
[6,9,12,18,24,27,30,36,42,45,48,54,60,63,66,69,72,78,81,84,90,96,99]
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this...

```
l = list({x for y in divisor_list for x in range(1,100) if not x % y} )
```