# Get True if all values are False and get False if there is at least one True value python

Tags: python, list

I would like to know how can I accomplish this.
I have a list like this one:

```
lst = [False, False, False]
```

I want to get `True` if all the elemments are `False` and in case the list have at least one `True` element wherever the position `lst=[False, True, False]` I want to get `False`.

I know it can be done with `any()` or `all()` but I have not been able to get the solution I want.

I was starting with something like this:

```
if not any(lst)
   print("something")
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099561/test-if-all-elements-of-a-python-list-are-false) and something links more but not get the expected solution.

Hope not bother with this question. Thanks for reading me.

Comment: `not any(lst)` works. I don't know what your issue is.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your posted code does not show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a set:

```
>>> lst1 = [False, False, False]
>>> lst2 = [False, False, True]
>>> set(lst1)=={False}
True
>>> set(lst2)=={False}
False
```

Or negate `in`:

```
>>> not(True in lst1)
True
>>> not(True in lst2)
False
```

Or negate `any`:

```
>>> not(any(lst1))
True
>>> not(any(lst2))
False
```

These methods all assume that your list is only made up of `True` and `False`. If you want to test that, use `all`:

```
>>> all(e in {True,False} for e in lst1)
True
>>> all(e in {True,False} for e in lst2)
True
```

Or again, use sets:

```
>>> set(lst1)<={True,False}
True
>>> set(lst2)<={True,False}
True
```